# ASP.NET MVC in Data base modifed error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

how to resolved Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog

Comment: Post your connectionstring please.

Comment: Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Students\Practical5\Practical5\App_Data\Database1.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify an `Initial Catalog` parameter into the connectionstring:

```
Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\Students\Practical5\‌​Practical5\App_Data\‌​Database1.mdf;Initial Catalog=Database1;Integr‌​ated Security=True;User Instance=True
```